# how to use opensource controls in my UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, open-source

I am designing UI for a system application using Visual Studio 2010 and C# language, willing to use some opensource controls to give my bosses a surprise.
Please help me out with my initial steps like where and how do I get new controls.

Thanks in Advance, 
Ashmeet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may start with [Nuget package gallery](https://nuget.org/).
There are plenty of good free and open-source libraries available here. Also it provides easy and convenient way to manage and update your packages within Visual Studio.

Comment: I have installed the package , but unfortunately it did not put anything new in my toolbox . Am I looking at right place or I am going in wrong direction.

Comment: Check the [Nuget website documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog) to find out more info. One of possible options - create new solution, then right-click on "References" and choose "Manage Nuget packages"

Answer (score 1):

> willing to use some opensource controls to give my bosses a surprise.

Sure the surprise is not you getting fired?

Do not get me wrong, I am totally behind open source.

BUT: many open source licenses are tricky to deal with from an open source perspective. You seem to be basically clueless - I can tell you that if I would find a non authorized open source control in any of my software projects, the responsible programmer would go out of the door, THEN I would start checking licenses - because we have a process in place for adding new elements. Happens, but it must be approved first, possibly by legal. If oyu add a GPL control, you just handed your program over under GPL, for example.

I strongly suggest you do not surprise your boss th stuff others myay consider borderline unintelligent. Especially when you are unable to use Google, NuGet to start with.